# Ambiguous function call to itself

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to setup the mysql connector for c++. When I try to compile this code this error appears `/home/cjueden/programming projects/mysqlConnect/main.cpp|23|error: call of overloaded ‘get_driver_instance()’ is ambiguous` 
Please explain how to fix this as I am stumped.

**CODE**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
// #include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace sql::mysql;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    cout << "STarting the MYSQL STUFF \n";
    sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://192.168.1.2:3306", "root", "");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");
  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("insert into cTest (text) value ('testing and stuff')");
  cout << "inserted stuff\n";
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'cTest' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: \n";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message");
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: \n";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

**ERROR**

```
/home/cjueden/programming projects/mysqlConnect/main.cpp||In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:|
/home/cjueden/programming projects/mysqlConnect/main.cpp|23|error: call of overloaded ‘get_driver_instance()’ is ambiguous|
/home/cjueden/programming projects/mysqlConnect/main.cpp|23|note: candidates are:|
/usr/include/cppconn/driver.h|62|note: sql::Driver* get_driver_instance()|
/usr/include/mysql_driver.h|86|note: sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()
```

Comment: It seems that both `driver.h` and `mysql_driver.h` have a implementation of `get_driver_instance`, so we get an ambiguous call.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, so I commented out the `driver.h` but no change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version of get_driver_instance() in driver.h is in the global namespace, so here's one fix:

```
driver = ::get_driver_instance();
```

The compiler doesn't know which of the two functions to use. Based on what you're doing with the return value, I'm guessing you intended to use the one in driver.h.

Prepending double-colon (::) is a way to be more explicit when using stuff in the global namespace (like this function). It resolves the ambiguity.

Another fix would be to remove the earlier "using namespace sql::mysql;".

Comment: All of your suggestions give a new error of `main.cpp|| undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'|`